# Pausable Timer on separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I need timer running on separate thread that can be paused and resumed.
The `System.Threading.Timer` would be ok. but I notice that it spawns new threads even while I'm debugging the callback. I don't want next callback to started before first one is finished, I would like to pause the timer during execution of the callback.

- The `System.Threading.Timer` cannot be paused.
- I'm not going to measure any time so no `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`.
- In [this qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964192/c-sharp-how-to-pause-a-timer) someone implemented his own class deriving from `Timer` but I have no idea what timer is this - the `System.Threading.Timer` is sealed.
- `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` can be stopped but the callback is dispatched on UI thread and I'm not sure about portability of this class.

What should I do?

Comment: You could have a task go in a loop with a delay in between and just let that run.

Comment: Yes, I'm just writing a thread with a while loop right now, but thought there maybe some build-in way already provided.

Comment: You could use a normal timer but have the thing you're doing be a `Task` then every run you check the previous Task for completion or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead of using a timer just make it a loop with a delay:

```
public static async Task RepeatingTask()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "Doing cool stuff" );
        await Task.Delay( 2000 );
    }
}
```

And you can start it like this:

```
Task.Run( RepeatingTask );
```

---

**NOTE:** this will not do the trick if you need to fire every say 2 seconds exactly.