# C# novice, question about controlling timers created in a constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, timer

I have a class that creates a timer in the constructor.

The timer does exactly what I need it to do but I would also like to be able to use .Stop(); and .Start(); from the main program.

There is a lot more than this but this is enough to recreate my exact problem.

In the example below I have access to Monsters[index].M_timer but .Stop(); gives an error.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int index = 0;
            string name = "Spider";
            monster[] Monsters = new monster[100];
            Monsters[index] = Create_Monster(name);
            /*
            Monsters[1].M_timer.Stop(); <- not how I will be using this but I need the functionality here
            */
        }
        public static monster Create_Monster(string _name)
        {
            int timer = 0;
            if (_name == "Spider")
            {
                timer = 4000;
            }
            monster build = new monster(false, timer);
            return build;
        }
    }
class monster
    {
        public bool can_act;
        public int _timer;
        public object M_timer;

        public monster(bool _can_act, int _timer)
        {
            can_act = _can_act;
            Timer M_timer = new Timer();
            M_timer.Interval = _timer;
            M_timer.AutoReset = true;
            M_timer.Enabled = true;
            M_timer.Elapsed += TimerEvent;
        }
        public void TimerEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            can_act = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the error message to this question?

Comment: Also what kind of Timer? Don't you need the StopWatch?
Timer is from the System.Threading?

Comment: Its a timer for how long a monster sleeps before it gains the ability to act. Once the action happens the flag for can_act goes back to false until the time elapses again.

The start/stop functionality is for if I want to pause a monster or if they die I need to be able to dispose of the timer.

I got it working though. The mistake was calling the timer a generic object instead of an actual timer in the main program, silly mistake I just didn't see.

Answer (score 1):

An initial glance looks like you have a couple of issues.  first, is scope.  You have in your constructor a variable called M_timer which covers the class field M_timer.  You are not acting upon the same objects here.  You'd have to say something like `this.M_timer = M_timer.`

The second issue is that you'd have to cast the class field when you want to use it because it's a generic object. so you'd have to say something like `((Timer)Monsters[1].M_timer).Stop()`

Answer (score 0):

Damn, I should have given this just a few more minutes:

public object M_timer;

replaced with

public Timer M_timer;

Comment: this fixes one of your issues but remember that in the constructor you are acting on a different timer.  You create 2 variables which have the same name.  Due to the way scoping works it acts upon the inner variable and ignores the outer variable with the same name.  for clarity it would be better to either a) just use the public timer that you created, or be, use different names and assign the class timer to the constructor's timer:  this.M_timer = mtimer

Comment: Not too worried about the naming conventions. I am retired and doing this just for myself and for fun.

I do care though a great deal about learning how this all works and you guys have been awesome so far (I likely have read 100 threads figuring stuff out on my own).

Comment: it's not so much a matter of naming convention, just a matter that you may get unexpected behavior since they are different objects.  if you have any additional questions feel free to ask, though

Comment: I do actually. I see that there is no .Pause();

if I wanted to do the following:

X= current value of timer
timer.Stop();
timer.Interval =X
timer.Start();

What would the actual syntax be?

Comment: you want to resume where it left off?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure with timer, but I know Stopwatch you can just say .Start() and .Stop() then it will resume where it left off.  It also has .Reset() and .Restart() to start back from 0

Comment: here's a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964192/c-sharp-how-to-pause-a-timer